# Linq code refactoring

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Please help me to refactor this code using Linq. How to use Where and ToList only once?
Thx for help

```
private IEnumerable<SomeClass> Filter(IEnumerable<SomeClass> aaa, string name, string company, string address,int? age)       
{
    var ans = new List<SomeClass>();         
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        ans = aaa.Where(x => x.name.equal(name)).ToList();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(company))
        ans = ans.Where(x => x.company.equal(company)).ToList();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        ans = ans.Where(x => x.address.equal(address)).ToList();

    if (age.HasValue)
        ans = ans.Where(x => x.age == age.Value).ToList();

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: You can use Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>> exp create following each condition at here. And code like this: ans = ans.Where(exp).ToList()

Comment: This is a weird method; if you supply `null` for the `name`, but actual values for the other parameters, `ans` will still be empty. I doubt that is what you meant to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var ans = aaa.Where( x => ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                            || x.name.equal(name)
                          )
                          &&
                          ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(company)
                            || x.company.equal(company)
                          )
                          &&
                          ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(address)
                            || x.address.equal(address)
                          )
                          &&
                          ( !age.HasValue
                            || x.age == age.Value
                          )
                   );
```

Comment: The `.ToList()` is not strictly necessary, because the method returns `IEnumerable<>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop all calls to `ToList`. Without those calls, the combined filtering will be executed in a deferred way that you don't need to care about.

If you do want to influence the time at which filtering is executed (or make sure the result is based on the snapshot of `aaa` at the time of invocation of `Filter` and does not change if `aaa` changes later on), change your last line to

```
return ans.ToArray();
```

(a list is probably not necessary here; the returned value is typed to `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` anyway and callers shouldn't expect to be able to directly modify (add/remove items) the returned object.

Thus, the complete code would look like this:

```
private IEnumerable<SomeClass> Filter(IEnumerable<SomeClass> aaa, string name, string company, string address,int? age)       
{
    IEnumerable<SomeClass> ans = new SomeClass[0];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        ans = aaa.Where(x => x.name.Equals(name));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(company))
        ans = ans.Where(x => x.company.Equals(company));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        ans = ans.Where(x => x.address.Equals(address));

    if (age.HasValue)
        ans = ans.Where(x => x.age == age.Value);

    return ans.ToArray();
}
```

As other answers have shown, it is also possible to combine all `Where` calls into one, though sticking with your original chain of `if`s and `Where`s shows very clearly what it does, which might not be true for the combined solutions.

Comment: O.R Mapper.. This code doesn't compile. The `equal` should be `Equals` and you are trying to convert an `IEnumerable<>` to `List<>`, your code must call the `ToList()` extension method after each statement in order to compile. Additionally why return the `ToArray()` this will force enumeration of the `IEnumerable<>` just to cast back to an `IEnumerable<>` Just a few notes.

Comment: @Nico: Thanks, I was overzealous at copying the code from the question, which is how `equal` was created. I have changed the type of `ans` to something that is sufficient here. As for `ToArray()`, as explained in my answer, it may or may not be desirable to force the immediate enumeration, depending on whether subsequent changes to the collection passed as `aaa` should be reflected in the returned enumeration or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another answer here. Why create a List at all your input is an IEnumerable and so is your output is the same?

```
private IEnumerable<SomeClass> Filter(IEnumerable<SomeClass> aaa, string name, string company, string address, int? age)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        aaa = aaa.Where(x => x.name.Equals(name));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(company))
        aaa = aaa.Where(x => x.company.Equals(company));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        aaa = aaa.Where(x => x.address.Equals(address));

    if (age.HasValue)
        aaa = aaa.Where(x => x.age == age.Value);

    return aaa;
}
```

Comment: This slightly differs from the OP's code: If none of the filters is applied, the original code will return an empty enumeration, whereas yours will return the entire `aaa` enumeration. Not sure whether that behaviour is intended by the OP, though.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on the subject:

1. I don't think you need to simplify the method to one `Where` clause because if you keep it this way, you can easily add new filter parameters later and your code would be quite readable.
2. You don't need to specify `ToList()`.
3. Instead of `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` consider using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. This way, you will not filter out entities if a non-empty but whitespace string is provided.
4. Instead of `x.name.Equals(name)` consider using `x.name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` **if** appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var ans = aaa.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? x.name.equal(name) : false).ToList()
             .Union(aaa.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(company) ? x.company.equal(company) : false).ToList())
             .Union(aaa.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(address) ? x.address.equal(address) : false).ToList());

ans = ans.Where(x => age.HasValue ? x.age == age.Value : true).ToList();
```

Comment: The filters in the question are combined in a conjunction. You are combining them in a disjunction, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea performance wise, since you iterate the list multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
private static IEnumerable<SomeClass> Filter(IEnumerable<SomeClass> aaa, string name, string company, string address, int? age)
{

        var ans = aaa.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? x.Name.Equals(name) : true)
                 .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(company) ? x.Company.Equals(company) : true
                     && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) ? x.Address.Equals(address) : true
                     && age.HasValue ? x.Age == age.Value : true);


        return ans;
}
```

But note that in your code, you always return 0 results if the "name" parameter is empty.